# REST API inside electron

Tags: api, express, electron

I have API that has been built using express.js. I want to build a similar app using electron.js. Is there any way to use express API in electron without the need of rewriting everything?

Answer (score -1):

No. It's not possible. Electron is a native app framework, whereas Express is made for servers. You could host your API and use `fetch` or AJAX request to your server, but it would be better if you rewrite your code.